# Is chaining indexeddb commands a bad idea?

Tags: indexeddb

The following code works correctly:

```js
var trans = window.db.transaction('abc')
var store = trans.objectStore('abc')
var reqst = store.get(123) 
reqst.onsuccess = success
reqst.onerror = error

function success(response) {}
function error(response) {}
```

Is this a bad idea:

```js
var reqst = window.db.transaction('abc')
  .objectStore('abc')
  .get(123) 
reqst.onsuccess = success
reqst.onerror = error
```

I'm thinking specifically of what happens if an error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a bad idea, it is just a matter of stylistic preference. I prefer the former over the latter because I think it is more readable and simpler to debug.